# Referencing instantiation of class inside another class

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

The title of the question may be very weird, but I had no idea how to word it otherwise. I'm looking for some help in understanding class instantiation and variable referencing in Python, particularly when a class variable is an instance of another class. I'll use the `dlipower` Python module since that's what I'm working with right now.

`dlipower` is comprised of two classes, `dlipower.PowerSwitch()` and `dlipower.Outlet(switch)`. `Outlet(switch)` requires an instance of `PowerSwitch()` as its first argument. I wrote up a class that utilizes both of of these classes, but I have no idea how to reference the instance of `PowerSwitch` without instantiating it in every function I have. I am doing something similar to the following right now:

```
import dlipower
class dli:
   switch = dlipower.PowerSwitch()  # should this be here?
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def PowerOn(self, port):
      switch = dlipower.PowerSwitch()  # this is what I want to remove
      outlet = dlipower.Outlet(switch)
      outlet.on(port)
```

I've been coding Python code a while but still very new to OOP, so any tips and pointers would be of great help.

Comment: Have you tried `dli.switch`?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a single answer to this question. What are the semantics associated with what switch you pass to the `Outlet` constructor? If you reuse it, does it work differently? If it's shared between many `dli` instances, does that matter? It's not clear to me why you have a `dli` class at all, since you don't ever use it to store any data (as attributes).

Comment: @Blckknght the only reason I have a dli class is to share the instantiation of `switch` among all methods in `dli`. I only put in one function  here to illustrate my point, but what I actually have re-creates an instances of `PowerSwitch()` which is what I suspect is slowing down the script. `switch` is the same throughout the class, and there's no difference in various uses. For this particular class, I have no need for any attributes besides `switch`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I have, but Python was returning an error stating that `dli` doesn't have that attribute, or something along those lines. I just wrote up a mini script and it worked just fine, I must have referenced something incorrectly. I'll try implementing it again and let you know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your method to access a class variable, you need to access it via the class name or via `self`. Either one should work:

```
class dli:
    switch = dlipower.PowerSwitch()
    # no need for an empty __init__ method
    def PowerOn(self, port):
        outlet = dlipower.Outlet(dli.switch)
        outlet.on(port)
```

Or:

```
class dli:
    switch = dlipower.PowerSwitch()
    def PowerOn(self, port):
        outlet = dlipower.Outlet(self.switch)
        outlet.on(port)
```

This still recreates the `outlet` every time you call `PowerOn`, but perhaps that's cheap...

You don't really need a class for this. The class variable `switch` is just a global variable tucked away in the class namespace. Since you don't have any other attributes (either class attributes or instance attributes), it might be simpler to just use an actual global instead:

```
# no dli class needed any more, just use top level variables and functions!

_switch = dlipower.PowerSwitch() # create a global PowerSwitch

def PowerOn(port):
    outlet = dlipower.Outlet(_switch)
    outlet.on(port)
```

I've used a name with an underscore for the global variable. That tells any other programmers looking at the code that it is an internal implementation detail, not part of your module's API. It's not "private" in the way some other programming languages mean (where the compiler prevents other code from accessing it), but it's Python's version of being private (where other code is *discouraged*, but not *prevented* from accessing internal stuff).

Speaking of naming conventions, you might want to change yours. The most common convention for Python code is to use `CaptializedNames` only for classes, and `lower_case_names_with_underscores` for most other things (functions, variables, etc.). Using a different convention isn't *wrong* per se, but it may make it more difficult for others to read your code.

Comment: I've tried both ways in my main script and I'm still getting the same issue that `switch` is uninstantiated. I try the exact same methods in a separate script and they work just fine. I made sure of my class instantiations and my globals, but I still have no clue what could be going wrong.... thank you for the tips, by the way :)

Comment: i figured out what the problem was: i was instantiating the `switch` with a blank password variable, even though i change the variable later on in the script, it still istantiates with no password, which is what was causing the error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass a specific instance of a PowerSwitch object into the Outlet object you're instantiating within the PowerOn function, pass it into the function as an argument, as such:

```
def PowerOn(self, port, switch):
  outlet = dlipower.Outlet(switch)
  outlet.on(port)
```

Then, whenever you want to instantiate a new Outlet, just instantiate the PowerSwitch before the function call, and include it as an argument.

In order to reference a variable from outside a given function within a function, that variable must either be global (created outside any function or class), a class variable (created outside a function within a class), a variable created within the function, or an argument provided with the function.